# Import data problem in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, import

I want to import data from one database to another.  On the destination database, I don't have permission to restore a backup file to it, so I have only one option which is to import data.

I used the wizard and I set the option of allow identity insert, but after it ran I faced a problem with foreign keys insertion. Is there anything I missed or shall I drop the foreign keys and recreate it after import?

I really wonder why Microsoft made it complicated.

Comment: Have you tried just disabling the FK constraints, import, then enable them again. e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/75882/how-can-i-import-data-using-sql-servers-ssis-when-using-foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 1):

You could drop the foreign keys, but if the tables are large and/or you have busy environment, be sure to test your insert times before you do anything on production.
In regard to new keys, it shouldn't throw a problem, but if you're trying to insert duplicate keys then you'll get errors.
Also, be sure to insert parent entities first (if you don't drop foreign constraints first!) then child entities.

Answer (score -1):

```
**Insert the parent entity first then their child otherwise it will conflict the  **FOREIGN** KEY Constraint.**
```